# The login form isn't rendered

Tags: forms

I am newbie to drupal. Recently I changed blocks of my theme and set main page content block to none.I logged out of my site. I tried to access admin panel by appending /user at URL. It redirected to login page but it login form is not appearing as displayed in image below. I am unable to enter my username and password.

[image: Drupal login form]

Any helps are welcomed.

Comment: the login block & login pages are not linked in that way, have you tried in another browser or clearing cache?

Comment: @th0ward I tried clearing cache and also tried it in another browser but it is not working

Comment: if you've got drush installed you can use drush uli admin (or your admin user name) in command line. copy the link into the browser and you should be logged in, you can then put the block back etc.

Comment: the only other thing I think can of is do you have a custom template file for the login page do you? If so remove that, clear cache and try again.

Comment: @th0ward i' using responsive green theme (https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_green) . I could not figure out whether there is login page in template file

Comment: @stackoverflowuser Since it's on /user, the login page should render the form. This points to the template/theme overriding the page or form inappropriately. Review the templates in your `responsive_green` theme and delete temporarily to test.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser the template will be the themes templates folder and if there is one thats overriding the default one it'll be called user-login.tpl.php Is the site available online somewhere so we can take a look and inspect the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to open phpmyadmin from your hosting, and look in the "block" table.

[image]

Look for the "main" block, and edit the status to "1" and the region to "content" (or whatever your main region is defined as in your themes .info file).

It seems strange that disabling the main content block would hide the login form though, I thought they were separate.

Comment: trying out your suggestion didn't helped either

Comment: Why didnt it help? Was the main block not enabled again? Did you enable the block on your selected theme? Did you get the region right?
What about if you enable the user login block and use that to login?

Comment: This isn't necessary relevant, since it's on /user, the login page should render the form. This points to the template/theme overriding the page or form inappropriately. Review the templates in your `responsive_green` theme and delete temporarily to test.

Comment: The content block is the one showing the content of the page, including any form, as in the case of the login form.