# I've placed blocks in hidden region, now no login to admin possible

Tags: users, blocks

I made a site in Drupal 9. I played a bit with blocks and I think I placed an important block in the hidden region. Now the login page doesn't show the login form anymore. The header, footer and some content are visible. I can't log in as administrator and I can't put the blocks back in another region.

I've searched the forums and Google thoroughly, but I couldn't find the answer.
The suggestion given in
[Drupal login form hidden](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161178/drupal-login-form-hidden)
to access http://example.com?q=user doesn't work.

I also looked to the database content, without finding anything. There are a lot of block tables, but they contain values of custom blocks, no default blocks like the login block.

Comment: I'd try installing drush and using `drush uli`. That will log you in (and I think force you to reset your password?) and  you should be able to access block layout and fix your blocks.

Comment: Is there a login form at /user/login ?

Comment: I've locked myself out of site too when I was first learning Drupal :D the same way you did and many others. The login block isn't the main login route, although it is more convenient. You can always get to the login page through the /user path, as already mentioned in comments. If you don't have clean URLs enabled on your host then the link is ?q=user, but most lof them have it so it's `/user` or `/user/login`. It is also possible to find the Login block under the enabled theme and set it to show up in a region, but it's much easier to do that through the interface, after you login :)

Comment: /user, /user/login, show a page with Log in as title, so the page is correct, but the form with username and password doesn't show up. I'll try the drush, but I first have to find out how to install and use this.